# How to set color tags to collection with Python?

Tags: python, collections

I’m trying to set a color tag to a collection with Python by using the collection name. How can I do that ?

Have a nice coding day !

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**[`Collection.color_tag`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Collection.html#bpy.types.Collection.color_tag)**

Set one of the pre-designated colors using the `color_tag` ENUM

```
>>> C.collection.color_tag
'NONE'
```

Consult the docs, or crunch in an incorrect value to get the list of valid values

```
>>> C.collection.color_tag = 'FOO'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: bpy_struct: item.attr = val: enum "FOO" not found in ('NONE', 'COLOR_01', 'COLOR_02', 'COLOR_03', 'COLOR_04', 'COLOR_05', 'COLOR_06', 'COLOR_07', 'COLOR_08')
```

Set it to red,

```
>>> C.collection.color_tag = 'COLOR_01'
>>>
```

Comment: Handy ! Link to the docs : https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Collection.html?highlight=color_tag#bpy.types.Collection.color_tag